# simple tower of hanoi code , how to reduce time limit to 3 second instead of 5 secs

Tags: java

here, i'm getting runtime of 5 seconds, what should i do reduce it to 3 secs.help me out here.

import java.util.*;

```
class GFG {
    public void solution(int n,int s,int a,int e){
        if(n==1){
         System.out.println(s+ " " +e);    
        }
        else{
            solution(n-1,s,e,a);
            System.out.println(s+ "->" +e);
            solution(n-1,a,s,e);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        //code

        GFG hom=new GFG();
        System.out.println("engter number of disks:");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int dish=sc.nextInt();
        hom.solution(dish,1,2,3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using your own data structure to hold a stack, instead of using recursion.  (Actually, I don't know how much this would help.  But in the situations I'm familiar with, the overhead of a call can be significant.)

Answer (score 0):

I havent checked the logic but on sites like GFG ur output should print fast so I have used StringBuilder.

Check if this works

```
public class GFG {
static StringBuilder sb;
public void solution(int n,int s,int a,int e){
    if(n==1){
     sb.append(s+ " " +e+"\n");    
    }
    else{
        solution(n-1,s,e,a);
        sb.append(s+ "->" +e+"\n");
        solution(n-1,a,s,e);
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    //code
    sb=new StringBuilder();
    GFG hom=new GFG();
    System.out.println("enter number of disks:");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int dish=sc.nextInt();
    hom.solution(dish,1,2,3);
    System.out.println(sb);
}
}
```